# vs code is showing this error, have installed django 2.1 in the system but still it is showing this error , can anyone suggest how to solve

Tags: python, django

Import "django.db" could not be resolved from source Pylance

from django.db import models- while importing models module above said error message was showing.
I am working locally, not on a venv.

Comment: Do you work with a virtual enviroment?

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment? Or is it working locally?

Comment: no I am working locally.

Comment: Really hard to guess the problem